# Showing UIButton Done on UIScrollview for images

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview

Want to show `UIButton` done on `UIScrollView` for images. With the below code `UIButton` is showing but when I scroll `UIImageView`s, it shows only on very first imageview where as I want `UIButton` done should show on all image views in `UIScrollView`.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad

 {
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 35);

[myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

[myButton.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];

myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;

myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

[myButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];

[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];
imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
    CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imageScrollView addSubview:myButton];
    [imageView release];
   }
imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:imageScrollView];
[imageScrollView release];
 }
```

How should I code it that `UIButton` Done should show on all image views when I scroll it.

Comment: add your button code in for loop so it add on each row...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your `UIButton` in for loop i.e. it can add each time when your new `ImageView` is add.
And change its `x_Origin` for each `imageView` -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIScrollView *imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

    imageScrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) 
    {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, 60, 35);
        [myButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [myButton.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

       [myButton.layer setCornerRadius:10.0f];
        myButton.layer.borderWidth = 2;
        myButton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];

        NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", i];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
        [imageScrollView addSubview:myButton];
    }

    imageScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:imageScrollView];

}
```

Remove these 2 lines

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:button animated:YES];
```

There is no need to do this. This means you're setting that button on `rightBarButton` of `NavigationBar` but in your case i think you dont want to do so.

Comment: thanks. after changing xOrigin for each image view. Now UIButton Done is showing in all image views.

Answer (score 0):

Set frame for myButton in for loop similar to imageview frame.

```
myButton.frame= CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.myButton.frame.size.width, self.myButton.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: i added like this NSInteger numberOfViews = 61;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;
        myButton.frame= CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.myButton.frame.size.width, self.myButton.frame.size.height); but done button is now not showing at all.